# One third of my house has no power

Tags: electrical

In my basement I have 2 outlets with no power, and a 220 with partial power and in the kitchen above I have some outlets not working, and on the second floor in the bedroom the outlets don't work.  Every once in awhile the circuits come on for a short while for no apparent reason then go back off for months.  Any ideas out there ?

Comment: When you say 220 with partial power are you measuring with a volt meter? Is there 120 to ground on 1 side and nothing or ? To ground on the other side? What type of power panel do you have circuit breakers? fuses? Is there more than 1 panel? A bit more info would be needed to help troubleshoot

Comment: What make and model is your electrical panel?

Comment: Call your power company and report partial lights out.  It's sounds like you're intermittently losing one phase of your power feed.

Comment: VTC OP never responded it has been a year not enough information provided.

Answer (score 1):

Since the power is intermittent, this indicates a circuit that is being made and broken, and could end in a high-resistance state, rather than *off* or *on*. That spot with high resistance would get *very* hot if there is a substantial load, possibly leading to a fire in a circuit box or in the wall itself.

Bring in a certified electrician to fix this, rather than risk a house fire.

Comment: This could be something as simple as a bad circuit breaker.  It could be a bad panel FPE panels with Stab-lock breakers are one example. Since this has been going on for an extended time we need to help narrow the problem down and possibly help the OP fix it. If every response were to call a professional there would be no need for this forum.